# Create quote summary of calculated fields

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form that allows users calculate cost of services. I can use the form to output the total price of the selected services via checkbox and input values * the data-price. However, I would also like to create a summary of the services they selected.

I sample of the results I am trying to achieve from my provided fiddle:

This assumes Text 1 has an input of 3 and the first two checkboxes are checked

```
Quote
Text 1        $29.85
Checkbox 1    $19.90
Checkbox 1    $45.95
Total         $95.70
```

I want to use a data attribute (like how I use data-price) inside the input and checkbox fields due to the actual complex of my input labels.

https://jsfiddle.net/evvaw9ta/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can add a `data-name` attribute to the inputs so that we know what name to display in the summary. Then, with a div with id `quote-summary` in your HTML, you can use this JS function to calculate the sum and display the summary:

```
function calculateSum() {
  var summary = [];
  var sum = 0;
  $("input.quote-input, .special-input:checked").each(function() {
    if ($(this).prop('checked') || (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length !== 0)) {
      var multiplier = $(this).prop('checked') ? 1 : parseFloat(this.value);
      var price = parseFloat($(this).data('price')) * multiplier;
      var name = $(this).data('name');
      sum += price;
      summary.push(name + '\t$' + price.toFixed(2));
    }
  });

  $("#quoteTotal").html(sum.toFixed(2));
  $('#quote-summary').html(summary.join('<br>'));
}
```

Here's a Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3ef3ypLz/

Answer (score 2):

You can create summary like this. You will have to give apt names to the form elements to create proper summary.

```
<script >
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("input.quote-input").each(function() {
        $(this).keyup(function() {
          //alert($(this).attr('data-price')); 

            var price = parseFloat($(this).data('price')) * parseFloat(this.value);
            price = price.toFixed(2);
            var quotename = $(this).attr('name');              
          if(this.value) {

            //$(".quote-sumamry").append(quotename +" $"+ price + " <br/>");
            var summary;

            if($("#" + quotename).length == 0) {
              //it doesn't exist                
              summary = "<div id='"+quotename+"'>"+ quotename +" $" + price + " </div>\n";
              $(".quote-sumamry").append(summary);
            }
            else {
              $("#"+quotename).html(quotename +" $"+ price + " <br/>");
            }  
            $("#"+quotename).show();
          }
          else {
            $("#"+quotename).hide();
          }

          calculateSum();
        });
      });
      $(".special-input").click(function() {
         //alert($(this).is(':checked'));
            var price = $(this).attr('data-price');
            var quotename = $(this).attr('name');
           // $(".quote-sumamry").append(quotename +" $"+ price + " <br/>");              
         if($(this).is(':checked')) {
            var summary;
            if($("#" + quotename).length == 0) {
              //it doesn't exist
            //  alert("here");
              summary = "<div id='"+quotename+"'>"+ quotename +" $" + price + " </div>\n";
              $(".quote-sumamry").append(summary);
            }
            else {
              $("#"+quotename).html(quotename +" $"+ price + " <br/>");
            } 
            $("#"+quotename).show();
         }
         else {
            $("#"+quotename).hide();
         }
         calculateSum();

      });
    });

    function calculateSum() {
      var sum = 0;
      $("input.quote-input").each(function() {
        if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
          sum += parseFloat($(this).data('price')) * parseFloat(this.value);
        }
      });

      $(".special-input:checked").each(function() {
        sum += parseFloat($(this).data('price'));
      });

      sum = sum.toFixed(2);

      $("#quoteTotal").html(sum);

    }


</script>
```

Comment: this sort of works. However, I have two errors. If I type in the amount in a text field and hit any key then it continues to add to the summary (but not the quote total). Also, it does add the value from the input it just adds the initial price it does remove or update when I change anything. i would like for it to show the total price from that field. So if they enter 1 it would technically work. However, if they entered to the summary would not be correct. https://jsfiddle.net/evvaw9ta/1/

Answer (score 2):

Is this the sort of thing you were after....

```js
        $(document).ready(function() {
      $("input.quote-input").each(function() {
        $(this).keyup(function() {
          //alert($(this).attr('data-price'));  
          var price = $(this).attr('data-price');
          var quotename = $(this).attr('name');
          $(".quote-summary").append(quotename +" $"+ price + " <br/>");
          calculateSum();
        });
      });
      $(".special-input").click(function() {
      console.log('click');
        //  alert($(this).attr('name'));
          var price = $(this).attr('data-price');
          var quotename = $(this).attr('name');
          $(".quote-summary").append(quotename +" $"+ price + " <br/>");            
        calculateSum();
      });
    });

    function calculateSum() {
      var quote = 0;
      $('input').each(function() {
        var span = $('span#'+this.id)
        if ( span ) {
          if ( this.type == 'checkbox' ) { 
            if ( this.checked ) { 
                quote += parseFloat(document.querySelector('span#'+this.id).innerHTML = this.getAttribute('data-price')) 
            } else { 
                document.querySelector('span#'+this.id).innerHTML = ''; 
            }
          } else if ( this.type == 'text' ) {
              var value = parseFloat(this.value); 
              if ( !isNaN(value) ) { 
                document.querySelector('span#'+this.id).innerHTML = ((value * this.getAttribute('data-price')).toFixed(2)); quote += (value * this.getAttribute('data-price')); 
              } else {
                document.querySelector('span#'+this.id).innerHTML = '';
              }  
          } 
        }
      });
      var sum = 0;
      $("input.quote-input").each(function() {
        if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
          sum += parseFloat($(this).data('price')) * parseFloat(this.value);
        }
      });

      $(".special-input:checked").each(function() {
        sum += parseFloat($(this).data('price'));
      });

      $("#quoteTotal").html(sum.toFixed(2));
    }
```

```css
    div.quote-total {
  width: 300px;
  float: left;
}
span {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}
span:empty {
  display: none;
}
span#Text_1:before {
  content: 'Text 1 : $';
  width: 90px;
}
span#Text_2:before {
  content: 'Text 2 : $';
  width: 90px;
}
span#Text_3:before {
  content: 'Text 3 : $';
  width: 90px;
}
span#Text_4:before {
  content: 'Text 4 : $';
  width: 90px;
}
span#CheckBox_1:before {
  content: 'CheckBox 1 : $';
  width: 90px;
}
span#CheckBox_2:before {
  content: 'CheckBox 2 : $';
  width: 90px;
}
span#CheckBox_3:before {
  content: 'CheckBox 3 : $';
  width: 90px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input">
Text 1
  <input id="Text_1" type="text" name="1" size="5" maxlength="2" class="quote-input" data-price="9.95">
  Checkbox 1
  <input id="CheckBox_1" type="checkbox" name="special_1" value="1" id="1" class="checkbox-hidden special-input" data-price="19.90">
  Checkbox 1
  <input id="CheckBox_2" type="checkbox" name="special_1" value="2" id="2" class="checkbox-hidden special-input" data-price="45.95">
  Checkbox 1
  <input id="CheckBox_3" type="checkbox" name="special_1" value="3" id="3" class="checkbox-hidden special-input" data-price="69.95">
  Text 1
  <input id="Text_2" type="text" name="2" size="5" maxlength="2" class="quote-input" data-price="7.50">
  Text 1
  <input id="Text_3"type="text" name="10" size="5" maxlength="2" class="quote-input" data-price="17.95">
  Text 1
  <input id="Text_4" type="text" name="11" size="5" maxlength="2" class="quote-input" data-price="19.95">
</div>
<div class="quote">
  <div class="quote-header">
    Quote
  </div>
  <div class="quote-sumamry">

  </div>
  <div class="quote-total">

    <span id="Text_1"></span>
    <span id="CheckBox_1"></span>
    <span id="CheckBox_2"></span>
    <span id="CheckBox_3"></span>
    <span id="Text_2"></span>
    <span id="Text_3"></span>
    <span id="Text_4"></span>
    <span>total</span>
    <span class="quote-sum" id="quoteTotal">0.00</span>
  </div>
</div>
```